# How to unlock the Dock in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dock

While using a brand new MacBook Pro, with Touch Bar, somehow the Dock got locked.  I didn't do anything that I know of.  Nothing moves at all, in or out.  I'm trying to remove and add items, apps, and nothing takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unsettling contents-immutable. Run the following in Terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock contents-immutable && killall -HUP Dock
```

Comment: That is a duplicate of your answer on the other question - you should be marking this question as a dup not answering it.

Comment: @Mark I didn't remember my answer from 1.5 years ago, thanks for finding it

Comment: As so long ago that suggests there is another question as I saw it recently :(

Comment: This command totally worked for me, and it "unlocked" the dock.  There is no mention of the word "unlock" in the other question, so that's why I couldn't find it.  If you could add "unlock" to the question then people (or dummies like myself!) would find that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out and back in (or, if you're comfortable with the Terminal, try running `killall Dock`). That will cause the Dock to relaunch and may un-freeze it.

Comment: I ran that command and nothing changed.  There was a flash, but nothing changed.

Comment: I also tried deleting the prefs file and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Give logging a shot and back in (or, in case you're alright with the Terminal, take a stab at running killall Dock). That will make the Dock relaunch and may un-solidify it.